# 英語が残っている箇所: 新しいアカウントの確認

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URL: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/oauth/google?code=xxx

スクショ:

[image: 英語が残っている]

Comment: これは新しい機能のため、翻訳がまだ進んでいなかったです。翻訳を登録しましたので、今後適用するだろう。

Answer (score 1):

> Here's how you'll look on the site

アカウントをリンクすることで、他のサイトと共通のプロフィール表示になります:

(↑意訳です)

> Display Name

表示名

Comment: 「アカウントをリンクすることで、$provider$と共通のプロフィール表示になります:」にしました。その情報はどこから取ったを言わないとよくないと思います（他のサイトからログイン情報を使えば、そこのサイトが持っている情報を表示する）。その日本語がおかしかったら、言ってください。